# Duda con metodos static en Java

Tags: java

Tengo una duda con los metodos static de java, estoy haciendo un ejercicio donde tengo que hacer esto:

o   Métodos estáticos pedirNombre, pedirNif y activarDorsal sin argumentos que solicitan al usuario que introduzca cada uno de los datos de un corredor y devuelven tal dato validado (desde cada uno de estos métodos se llamará a cada uno de los métodos validadores).

Mi duda es, al decirme que tengo que que solicitar al usuario. Tengo que meter el scanner en este método para pedir los datos que me piden? No entiendo muy bien lo que quiere..

Dentro de pedir nombre se debe añadir también la validación hecha de los parametros que se piden, lo cual yo he hecho esto

```
public static boolean validarNombre(String nombre){

    return nombre.matches("^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\\/](0?[1-9]|1[012])[/\\/](19|20)\\d{2}$");

    }
```

A parte de pedir al usuario su nombre, debo meter en el metodo pedir nombre, la validación que he hecho para validar el nombre, ahora mismo lo tengo así

```
public static void pedirNombre(){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce Nombre");
        String nombre=teclado.nextLine();

    }
```

Como sería para meter esa validación dentro de pedir nombre?

Answer (score 0):

mmmm si no he entendido mal puedes en el mismo archivo del main un scanner que sea una variable de clase (para usarlo en todos los métodos estaticos que crees si la necesidad de instanciarlo en cada uno de ellos) entonces en cada método lo utilizas para pedir los datos que te piden y retornarlos.

```
static public Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String [ ] args)
{
  /*
   Aquí la llamada a los métodos o construcción del objeto
 */
}
```

Los métodos estaticos deben devolver la cadena de texto

```
public static string pedirNombre(){
        System.out.println("Introduce Nombre");
        String nombre=teclado.nextLine();
       //Validar el nombre como te han pedido
        return nombre;

    }
```

etc.

No sé si he podido aclararte algo :P.

Un Saludo!

Comment: Osea que en el metedo pedir nombre:

public static void pedirNombre(){
    
//aqui el scanner y validación del pedirnombre
    }

y en el main eso que has puesto?

Comment: Sí. Aun que no entiendo cuando dices validación a qué te refieres. En el método pedirNombre usas el scanner pides el nombre al user y lo devuelves. Entonces sería public static string pedirNombre()

Comment: Es que también me piden validar el el nombre, nif y demás.

public static void pedirNombre(){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce Nombre");
        String nombre=teclado.nextLine();
        
    }

ahora mismo lo tengo así, pero debería añadir la validación validarNombre en pedir nombre que es esto que he hecho:

public static boolean validarNombre(String nombre){
    
    return nombre.matches("^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\\/](0?[1-9]|1[012])[/\\/](19|20)\\d{2}$");
    
    }

Comment: las aclaraciones y todo el código faltante @Flowcou van en tu pregunta, si no se pierde el sentido de la misma y se tomará de baja calidad, editala por favor y ahi coloca todo eso

Comment: Como bien dice Shadow edita la pregunta y pon el código que tienes para poder ayudarte una mejor manera. Un saludo!

Comment: Editado, perdona.

Comment: La pregutna tiene alguna relación con que el método sea static?

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta de que el enunciado pone Métodos estáticos, si tiene relación....

Comment: Pregunta, lo de validar el nombre te refieres a que sean letras y no números o qué. Por que no termino de entender tu regex. (igual es fallo mío)